# A LaTeX3 new macro/function definition problems

Tags: programming, expl3, latex3

I noob in LaTeX3 and I try to understand this language.
As I read [here](http://latex-community.org/know-how/422-program-latex3)  one can define a new macro by using `\cs_new:`

```
\cs_new:Npn \SayHello #1
 { \prg_replicate:nn {#1} { Hello~World!~ } }
```

where `N` respect to `\SayHello`, `p`  --- to `#1` and `n` --- to `{...}`

Ok, I try to create my function to show square of some number:

```
\cs_new:Npn \Show #1 
{
\int_eval:n {#1*#1}
}
```

Macro `\Show{number}` work fine.
But if I try to define macro `\Show`, which should show me some integer:

```
\cs_new:Nn \Show 
{
\int_eval:n {2+2}
}
```

I get a `LaTeX error: "kernel/missing-colon"`.

Ok, then I add a colon:

```
\cs_new:Nn \Show:n 
{
\int_eval:n {2+2}
}
```

and I agein get an error, but now it just `! Undefined control sequence`.

This behavior is not clear to me. **Where am I breaking the rules?**

MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Nn \Show:n 
{
\int_eval:n {2+2}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\Show{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The functions with `p` allow for non - colon macro names, the other ones must have a colon at the end! You can't call `\Show` just this way outside of `expl3` space. You must define it with `Npn` or call it with `\Show:n{}` in expl3 space

Comment: Actually, expl3 space should be `\Show:` to work with `\cs_new:Nn`, or if you use `\cs_new:Npn` you can use whatever name you want. In any case, you should actually define `\Show` with `xparse` to make the public interface, and then the internal through `expl3` language. Of course, for this example is too much, but in general that should be the way.

Comment: You should do `\cs_new:Npn \sergio_show:  {...}` (without argument) or `\cs_new:Npn \sergio_show:n #1  {...}` (with argument) and define the document command in addition (with `xparse`): `\NewDocumentCommand \Show {} { \sergio_show: }` or `\NewDocumentCommand \Show {m} { \sergio_show:n {#1} }`

Comment: Why I should to use `xparse`, why not `LaTeX3` directly? In the first example it was possible.

Comment: @sergiokapone it is possible but doesn't follow the expl3/LaTeX3 conventions that if you define commands for use in the document they should have a code-level equivalent function. The code level function should also follow the naming conventions (`\<module>_<name>:<arg spec>`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `\cs_new:Nn` you're only allowed to define a function (macro) which has a *signature*, that is a list of the argument types after a colon.

With `\cs_new:Npn` you don't have this restriction, because you have to type in explicitly the parameter text (which is what `p` in the signature means).

For example, `\cs_new:Nn` expects a single token argument (`N`) and a braced argument (`n`). Conversely, `\cs_new:Npn` expects a single token argument, a “parameter argument” (see the discussion of *parameter text* in the TeXbook or TeX by topic) followed by a braced argument.

The codes

```
\cs_new:Nn \sergio_show:n { \int_eval:n { #1+#1 } }
```

and

```
\cs_new:Npn \sergio_show:n #1 { \int_eval:n { #1+#1 } }
```

are completely equivalent, because `\cs_new:Nn` can build a suitable parameter text from the signature.

If the command you want to define has no signature, you *must* define it with `\cs_new:Npn` or `\cs_new_protected:Npn`.

Alternatively, you can do

```
\cs_new:Nn \sergio_show:n { \int_eval:n { #1+#1 } }
\cs_set_eq:NN \Show \sergio_show:n
```

However, for user space commands, using the `xparse` interface is recommended.

You can't do

```
\cs_new:Nn \Show:n { \int_eval:n { #1+#1 } }
```

and then use `\Show` in the document, because you've never defined `\Show`.

Beware that you should use `\cs_new_protected:Npn` or `\cs_new_protected:Nn` (same rules apply) whenever the code contains non expandable functions (those without a red full or hollow star in the manual). Not the case here, because `\int_eval:n` is fully expandable.

Comment: Also note perhaps that `_show` would be wrong here as it's not a non-expandable function placing material in the `.log`/terminal.